# Compute Description Based on Specific Field

Tags: plone, dexterity

My custom dexterity type looks like this:

```
class IMyType(form.Schema):
    title = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Title"),
    )
    address = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Address"),
        required=False,
    )

class MyType(dexterity.Container):
    grok.implements(IMyType)
```

I want the Live Search result looks like this, listing its title and first 3 char of the address value if existing:

```
Item One
  Address[:3]

Item Two
  Address[:3]
```

By default, each item matched will show its title and description. Thus, one solution is making the description field computed from the address field. But I don't know how. Any hint or better suggestion?

Comment: Hi Marr, could one of the answers help/do you need more info?

Comment: These answers are appreciated and of great help. I probably needs them both in my case. Will find time to try them out.

Comment: I'd say it depends on your usecase. If you want the address to behave in general/globally like the description: go for mat's proposal. Though that assumes, you don't need a description for your contype at all, and then you could use the desc-field for adress-input anyway. If you only need this in the livesearch-results, go for customizing livesearch_reply.

Comment: Nice. Your comment deserves the best answer.

Comment: :D how sweet to diplomatically 'divide' possible points to give, to the two answers and glad you have all the infos now, you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the Description index for your specific type using plone.indexer.
This way the catalog has the right information and you don't have to customize the search result.

```python
from plone.indexer import indexer

@indexer(IMyType)
def custom_description(obj, **kw):
    return obj.Description[:3]
```

Register

```xml
<adapter name="description" factory=".indexers.custom_description" />
```

Check plone.indexer documentation on pypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.indexer

Answer (score 1):

Quoting http://somedoma.in:8080/somePloneSiteId/portal_catalog/manage_catalogSchema:

"It is important to understand that when the Catalog is searched, it returns a list of result objects, not the cataloged objects themselves, so if you want to use the value of an object's attribute in the result of a search, that attribute must be in this list"

So, after adding your fieldname to the metadata-index, you can customize livesearch_reply, to achieve what you want, insert after line 52 (Products.CMFPlone-4.3) where "display_description" is set, this:

```
if result.portal_type == 'yourtype':
    display_description = safe_unicode(result.address)
```